# Why does one of my floors have lights around it?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

I noticed when I started my game today that one of my floors has lights all around it (like marquee lights or something). What does this mean? What are they for?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: I have no idea how to get a picture of it - I am playing on Android if that helps

Comment: [like this?](http://www.tinytowervegaswiki.com/w/images/thumb/4/46/Player's_Club_Floor.png/400px-Player's_Club_Floor.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floor with the lights around it is the floor featured in the players' club tournament.  This lasts for 84 hours, or three and a half days.

> By joining a group, you can team up with others for a chance to win chips and other prizes.